# How to inject a service into every component in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js

I have a session service that I want to inject into every component, according to the docs, this should work:

```
app.register('service:session', Session, { singleton: true });
app.inject('controller', 'session', 'service:session');
app.inject('route', 'session', 'service:session');
app.inject('component', 'session', 'service:session');
```

It works for controllers and routes, but generated components do not pick up the service.

How can I make this work?

I know that some are going to say that giving a component access to a service is bad form, but then again, the Ember core team are advising that controllers are going to be replaced by route-able components and in which case it seems perfectly reasonable.

I am following this technique to shim route-able components in the meantime: http://emberigniter.com/should-we-use-controllers-ember-2.0/

Thanks!

Comment: Services are auto-registered if you're using Ember CLI. This should be working.

Comment: Yeah I'm using ember CLI, the above generally works, just not for the components. Not sure if this is a bug, or Ember purism trying to force you to keep components isolated from the global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use "reopen" Ember.Component. 
You can look to guide for [reopen and reopenclass](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances/)

Example:

```
Ember.Component.reopen({
    service: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

we can inject services to component. Did you try with the following?

```
service : Ember.inject.service('service')
```

**component.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    service : Ember.inject.service('service'),

    actions : {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is specifically with generated components, i.e. those where I don't have a .js file defining them.